# Unix side-by-side difference with a remote hidden file

Tags: shell, unix, diff, remote-access, ksh

I am working on a battery of automatic tests which executes on **2 Unix virtual machines** running with KSH. Those VMs are independant and they have practically the same **.profile** file. I would like to study their differences by launching:

```
tkdiff /usr/system/.profile system@{external_IP}:/usr/system/.profile
```

on the first VM but it doesn't work.

[image]

I suppose that directly accessing a hidden file is not possible. Is there a solution to my problem, or maybe an alternative?

Comment: Your `system@{external_IP}:/usr/system/.profile` isn't really a file. Try making a *process substitution* of it https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html like this `tkdiff /usr/system/.profile <(ssh system@{external_IP} cat /usr/system/.profile)` Though that may not work if `tkdiff` needs a seek-able file.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I tried your solution but I get this curious message: `Error: you specified 4 file(s) and 0 revision(s)`. I will read your web link and try something similar, thanks for your reply :)

Comment: I should have noted it is a *bash-ism*, so will only potentially work in `bash`.

Comment: Aïe I work with KSH :/ I updated my answer to notice that

Comment: If you use [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) you can get that

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is it possible to highlight text differences between two files with Emacs?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the filename convention "user@host:/path/to/file"  for the second argument to `tkdiff`.

That convention for naming is not native to Ksh, but instead is understood by some programs like `scp` and others (which can be interactive, e.g. to ask for a password for the remote system or other authentication related questions).

But from the `tkdiff` man page, it does not mention having built-in support for that filenaming convention *userid@host:/path/to/file*,  and neither is such support built into `ksh`.

So you may need to use two steps, first to use `scp` or similar to copy the remote file locally then then use `tkdiff` with one argument the local file and the other the file-just-copied, or arrange to `mount` part of the other VM filesystem locally, and then use `tkdiff` with appropriate arguments.

Obviously, both files need to be readable by your userid or the user specified on the userid@host:/path/to/file  for this to work.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay of my answer, I'll try your solution tomorrow at work

Comment: Thanks for your alternative solution, I mark your solution as valid as you have been the first to deliver a good answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to compare different files on two remote machines, I suggest the following procedure:

**1. Compare checksums:**

First compare the checksums. Use `sum`, `md5sum` or `sha256sum` to compute a hash of the file. If the hash is the same, the [probability](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18335) of having the same file is extremely high! You can even increase that probability by check the total amount of characters, lines and words, in the file using `wc`.

```
$ file="/usr/system/.profile"
$ md5sum "$file" && wc "$file"
$ ssh user@host "md5sum '$file' && wc '$file'"
```

**2. run a simple diff**

Run a simple diff using the classic command line tools. They understand the POSIX standard to use `-` as `/dev/stdin`. This way you can do:

```
$ ssh user@host "cat -- '$file'" | diff "$file" -
```

**note:** with old versions of `tkdiff` or new versions of svn/git, it  can be tricky here due to bugs in tkdiff. It will quickly throw errors of the form `svn [XXXX] file .... is not a working copy` or `file xxxx is not part of a revision control system` if one of the files might be under version control or you end up in a directory under version control. Stick to diff!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, first step of your solution is a very good idea, and the simple diff works well :) I will read some documentation about tkdiff

Answer (score 0):

You can directly made a remote ssh compare , run a remote display with help of cat command line, with this :

```
tkdiff <(ssh system@{external_IP}1 'cat /usr/system/.profile') <(ssh system@{external_IP}2 'cat /usr/system/.profile')
```

In your case to be able to compare with the local *.profile* file this :

```
tkdiff /usr/system/.profile <(ssh system@{external_IP} 'cat /usr/system/.profile')
```

Do you have just try with the simple diff command line (with -b -B option to remove blank line and space comparaison):

```
diff -b -B /usr/system/.profile <(ssh system@{external_IP} 'cat /usr/system/.profile')
```

Comment: Thanks for tour reply, I will try that when I go back to work tomorrow (I haven't tried diff for the moment)

Comment: I have tried the solution but it returns an error (`'(' unexpected`). The same event occurs when trying the `diff` solution.